# Texstudio and local texmf

Tags: texstudio, makefile

I have a project directory and within the project directory a package in a local `texmf`-tree. As the project resides in a repository and is compiled on different computers, I would like to have a compile command that first sets the `TEXMFHOME` variable and then executes `pdflatex`. Last, I use `texstudio v2.10.8`. How could I get this working?

In my real scenario I want the packages also to be found in multiple tex-files located in subfolders. Hence, the use of `TEXMFHOME`.

## MWE

I have a file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{foo}
\begin{document}
    \foo
\end{document}
```

and `foo.sty` in `texmf/tex/latex/`

```
\newcommand{\foo}{c}
```

Also, a file `Makefile` with content

```
MAIN=main

compile:
        export TEXMFHOME=./texmf/
        pdflatex $(MAIN).tex

.PHONY: clean force once all
```

From command line it works as expected. If I execute `/usr/bin/make` from `texstudio` it does not find `foo.sty`.

Comment: Might be more of a `make` or shell question (perhaps TeXstudio uses `/bin/sh` which may or may not be the same as `/bin/bash`). Have you tried `TEXMFHOME=./texmf/ pdflatex $(MAIN).tex` all on one line? Alternatively, three lines of `TEXMFHOME=./texmf/`, `export TEXMFHOME`, `pdflatex $(MAIN).tex`?

Comment: `TEXMFHOME=./texmf/ pdflatex $(MAIN).tex` seems to work. Do you have any ideas why that would work? I mean, usually I would use `;` to sequentialize commands. But then it does not work when calling from `texstudio`.

Comment: The one line version explicitly sets an environment variable for the following command, and that variable is deleted once that command finishes. Works in all Bourne-type shells, at a minimum (haven't used a non-Bourne shell in 20-25 years or so). If my 3-line option (set variable, export variable, run pdflatex) works as intended, and especially if you also see that `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash` instead of `bash`, then the problem is that `export NAME=value` is a bash-ism, and can't be expected to work in other Bourne-type shells. The three-line version is universal.

Comment: From within `make` it uses `/bin/sh` and from command line `/bin/bash`. Also, the three line version did not work from within `texstudio`...

Comment: Then you can't use a one-line `export NAME=value` inside the Makefile. You should be able to chain as many of those variables together as needed, though: `NAME1=value1 NAME2=value2 pdflatex $(MAIN).tex`.

Comment: It works with your suggestions, thanks! However, I do not understand why some things work when executed from command line (like any version using `export`), but not from within `texstudio`.

Comment: I'm assuming the Makefile works consistently, regardless if you run it from the command line or from TeXstudio. The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) indicates that it'll use `/bin/sh` as the default shell. If `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash, [it'll behave like this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html). If it's a symlink to [dash](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/) as I suspect, then bash-specific commands like `export N=v` won't work, any more than `\newcommand` would work with regular TeX.

Comment: @MikeRenfro, Is there a way to define variable in TeXStudio as part of a command? For instance, I tried `export LC_ALL="en_US";
lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` but it won't work. I need to set `LC_ALL="en_US"` in TeXStudio environment before running LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Royi if you’re not using `make` to build, these answers probably aren’t relevant. None of this is influenced by the editor. I suggest posting a separate question for better chances of getting an answer.