# TexStudio how to reference custom packages (local texmf tree)?

Tags: texstudio, texmf

In my project folder I created the file `project/texmf/tex/latex/mymacros.sty`. From the command line, I can use `export TEXMFHOME=texmf` 
and then everything works fine, `pdflatex` recognizes all commands defined in `mymacros.sty` after `\usepackage{mymacros}`.

How do I have to setup TexStudio so that it recognizes the files located in that folder? I tried to include `export TEXMFHOME=texmf` in the precompile but it throws an error:

`Error: Could not start the command: export TEXMFHOME=texmf`

Related:

- [How to add new packages to TeXStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181024/how-to-add-new-packages-to-texstudio) (I don't want to add the packages to my texlive distribution, as they belong locally to the project. (also crucial for making the project easier to export!) I am rather looking to a solution akin to python virtual environments -- [Is there a way to create Tex Live or LaTeX virtual environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448263/is-there-a-way-to-create-tex-live-or-latex-virtual-environment))
- [Texstudio and local texmf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386166/texstudio-and-local-texmf) (using makefiles instead -- I am using a makefile to bulk compile, however for here I am looking for a solution using vanilla TexStudio)
- https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/336 (Autocompletion for the .sty files)

Answer (score 1):

With a current texlive 2019 I would suggest to do

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/project/texmf
```

With a current miktex you can do

```
initexmf --register-root=path/to/project/texmf
```